# Autoheight in MUI DataGrid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I'm using the MUI `DataGrid` component, and the behavior I hope to have is that:

1. When there's a small number of rows, the table is only the size it needs to for those rows.
2. When there's a large number of rows, more than the current viewport can hold (given whatever else is on the screen), the table takes up the available space in the layout (given its `flex: 1`) and the extra rows scroll inside the table.

I can achieve each of these behaviors, but only one at a time.

1. If I use the `autoHeight` property on the `DataGrid`, then the table will be as small as it can be. BUT it will also be as big as it can be, so with a large number of rows the *container* scrolls the entire table, rather than the rows scrolling within the table.
2. If I don't use `autoHeight`, and wrap the `DataGrid` in a container with `flex: 1`, then the table will grow to fill the available space and the rows will scroll within the table. BUT a table with only a few rows will also grow to fill its container, so that there is empty space under the rows (above the footer, "Table rows: #")

You can see the situation in this screenshot, showing the exact same page, with different data.

[image]

I've tried what feels like every permutation of heights and flexes under the sun. For example:

- Setting autoHeight with a `maxHeight` (and `.MuiDataGrid-main { overflow: scroll; }` ) allows few-rows to be small, and many-rows to be not too small, but obviously any discrete `maxHeight`, be it px or %, is not the `flex`ible layout I'm going for.
- Turning off autoHeight (as in scenario #2) and setting `flex-grow: 0` on the rows container within the table (`.MuiDataGrid-main`) just makes the rows disappear since they then shrink to a height of 0.

The code for the component:

```js
const S = {
  Wrapper: styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background: white;
    border: solid thick red;
  `,
  DataGrid: styled(DataGridPro)`
    && {
      .MuiDataGrid-main {
        //overflow: scroll;
        //flex-grow: 0;
      }
      background: lightgreen;
      font-size: 14px;
    }  
`,
};

type Props = {
  columns: ReadonlyColumns;
  rows: AnyObject[];
  filterModel?: GridFilterModel;
} & Omit<DataGridProps, 'columns'>;

const DataTable: React.FC<Props> = ({
  columns = [],
  rows = [],
  filterModel,
  className,
  ...props
}) => {
  const memoizedColumns = useMemo(
    () =>
      columns.map(col => ({
        headerClassName: 'columnHeader',
        flex: 1, // all columns expand to fill width
        ...col, // but could override that behavior
      })),
    [columns],
  );

  return (
    <S.Wrapper className={className}>
      <S.DataGrid
        // autoHeight
        rows={rows}
        columns={memoizedColumns}
        filterModel={filterModel}
        {...props}
      />
    </S.Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 8):

Using a combination of `autoHeight` and `pageSize` will create a table whose height is only as big as needed for the current number of rows as long as the number of rows is `<= pageSize`. Additional rows will be added to a new page.

```js
<DataGrid
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    pageSize={20} //integer value representing max number of rows
    autoHeight={true}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Below solved the issue:

```
<DataGrid getRowHeight={() => 'auto'} />
```

Source:
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-height/#dynamic-row-height

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue days ago and I solved recalculating the row height every time a new item was added to my row.

```
getRowHeight={(props: GridRowHeightParams) => {
      const serviceRowHeight = 45 // <-- default height, if I have no data for the row
      const addServiceBtnHeight = 45 // <-- a component that's always on the row
      const height = props.model?.services // services is each dynamic item for my row, so you should access like props.yourObj
        ? props.model.services.length * serviceRowHeight + addServiceBtnHeight
        : 115
      return height < 115 ? 115 : height // final height to be returned
    }}
```

Comment: I had thought about that, but it's so...anti! It may have to be my solution.